What are some good ways to visualize one-hot encoded data
I'm working on a ML project where we want to visualize our one-hot encoded data to see how the model is learning. What are some good techniques for this? I'm aware of dimensional reduction methods. What other methods are there for visualizing/interpreting these sorts of data structures?

"visualizing" the data is actually quite vague. A histogram could work if you just convert the one-hot encodings to categories and want to count their occurrences, for example. Could you expand on what exactly you hope to see?

Yes apologies, we are moving through a high-dimensional one-hot encoded space and would like to visualize where we are going


I'm aware of dimensional reduction methods.

So, the only way to visualize the features is to transfer it into a 2D or 3D. There are lot of methods:

PCA (good for vizualization)
t-SNE (sometimes good for vizualization too)
TruncatedSVD
UMAP

I usually use several methods at once and visualize each one to choose the best baseline. For example:
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD

tsne = TSNE(n_components=2, random_state=RANDOM_SEED)
X_tsne = tsne.fit_transform(X_scaled)
svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=2, random_state=RANDOM_SEED)
X_svd = svd.fit_transform(X_scaled)

def decomp_plots(X_tsne, X_svd, hue=data['Class']):
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))

    plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
    sns.scatterplot(x=X_tsne[:, 0], y=X_tsne[:, 1], hue=hue, palette=colors, s=10)
    plt.title('t-SNE')

    plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
    sns.scatterplot(x=X_svd[:, 0], y=X_svd[:, 1], hue=hue, palette=colors, s=10)
    plt.title('TruncatedSVD')

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

decomp_plots(X_tsne, X_svd)

